# Unrecognised Arduino Uno

Tags: linux, arduino

I got my Arduino Uno and happend yesterday to stop being recognised by the computer.The red led on the board works, so that's a good sign , but when i connect it via usb it doesn't notify me in the down-right side of screen that some device has connected.
Also in Device Manager doesn't appear at all , not even as an unknown device.
I tried to rewrite the firmware in linux but at a point it says that the device is not plugged.
Is there anything software i can do?or it's a hardware problem?

Answer (score 0):

If there is problem with USB to TTL chip then this kind of problem happens.
You may check chip and replace chip.